# What is a good way to interpret an employer's response that "One third of testing is automated"?

Tags: interviewing

In a recent interview with one employer, running a relatively large local platform, mentions that one-third of their testing is automated. They are initially built on PHP but are migrating to various other backends such as NodeJS, Python, and even Go.

I interpreted that to mean the migration is actually not going well, due to lack of proper documentation, so the testing is difficult to automate. I've reverse engineered other people's code before and it is definitely NotFun™.

I also suspect that any employer would want nearly 100% of their testing automated, since there's just no good reason to stick a person on that role unnecessarily, and it forces proper documentation and this is self-evident in development methodologies such as TDD.

Am I being too harsh or is one-third automated testing as bad as I think it is?

Comment: I've got no real experience, but wouldn't some non-automated testing always be necessary for user interactions? Like, backend stuff is very easy to automate testing for, but it seems harder to do for visual things like websites. I'm not sure what their setup is, but I wouldn't take <100% automated testing as a necessarily red flag.

Comment: Do they have dedicated manual testers? or was this 1/3 is automated, 273 is tested manually by devekopers?

Comment: It means that you will have to write tests for other 2/3 :)  Honestly, it does not mean much, it is somewhere in the middle of the pack for large living (i.e. being developed) platform. Usually only applications that are in the maintenance mode get more than 50% automated test coverage. 100% test coverage is largely chimera.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is really a comp-sci question, ask on the QA site of Software site

Answer (score 5):

**Depends on what testing means there.**

It could mean one of four things. It could mean that 1/3 of testing is automated and 2/3rds of testing is handled manually. Or it could just mean that 2/3rds is not really tested at all.

I currently work for a startup with janky deadlines and previously worked for an institution with janky deadlines. It meant/means that plenty of features are just pushed out with tests being TODOs. The government institution officially talked about TDD too, but it was dispensed with as soon as stuff needed to get done.

I have friends everywhere from banks to FAANGM to startups to government. Full test coverage is not the case at any of them, but some have manual testers that poke at it. The rest, well, customers tolerate bugs nowadays.

So it could mean:

- Testing is difficult, so it is manually done.
- Testing is difficult, so it is just not really done.
- Testing is considered an extra, so not every feature gets tests.
- Testing is something to be done later, so it is a TODO

Comment: While I have never seen 100% coverage in companies, I've seen 80-90%. So some companies take it seriously. But I agree, they are the minority

Comment: Hmm, so asking them what the barriers are for the 2/3 would be a great second question. I've sadly worked in far too many companies where the QA is basically myself or totally opaque and gives no justification for rejections. I have no idea what is and isn't suppose to happen with automated testing. I only know academically want is suppose to happen, but that never happens in real life...

Comment: It might be that it's cheaper to pay minimum wage to manual testers than to get skilled engineers to write proper tests (and if necessary pay for specialized test software or hardware). It depends on how many times you're going to run the tests, the complexity of the functionality being tested, and the length of the project. But automated tests can be a massive time sink to write and maintain (particularly if the project isn't designed for testing).

Comment: @StuartF this is self defeating over time, since you want to develop your people so they aren't doing minimum wage work and being paid minimum wage forever. You can't if their time is taken up doing minimum wage work. They'll leave, or (hopefully) automate some things for you.